# Uploaded file showing 505 error on browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I have a form with an upload .After upload I am saving the file to a folder under /public_html/images/resumes/(here goes the uploaded files) in remote site set up. Here I am saving the uploaded file's name into a variable $filename. At the same time I am sending a mail using YII extension, in the mail I have included a link to open the files name in the browser for the admin to view like this

```
 <a href="http://www.hell.com/images/resumes/'.$fileName.'">Resume</a>'
```

When I open it, there shows of a 500 INTERNAL ERROR
I found that it is some permission problem related to .htaccess. I have added the following code to give permission to resumes folder.

Here is my code:

```
  #allowing access to resumes folder
  <Directory /images/resumes/>
   Options +Indexes
```

It isn't working. I have changed the folder name too like this/public_html/images/resumes/ , it too seems to not working

Here is my .htaccess can any one out there see the problem?

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
Options -Indexes

#allowing access to resumes folder
<Directory /images/resumes/>
Options +Indexes


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 100 years"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 100 years"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 100 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 100 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 100 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 100 years"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 100 years"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 100 years"

#disallows libwww-perl user-agents from accessing your site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]


#canonical urls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.hell.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hell.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#canonical ips
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^268\.61\.322\.654
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hell.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: Check your `error.log` to see what the actual error is.

Comment: @anubhava mine is a shared host,and i dont see error logs under the folders you have mentioned before

Comment: @anubhava is there any possibility i can set the permission to chmod($fileName, 777); as this or something

Comment: No, unless we know actual error from Apache error.log I won't be able to suggest any remedy.

Comment: how do you check your error.log can you please explain

Comment: Just ask your hosting co. where that file is and read the actual error log from it.